# NodeJS and Mysql with docker-compose 3 ERRCONNREFUSED

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I´m trying to built a docker-compose file to deploy locally my NodeJS app that connects to a mysql server. I´ve tried everything ( read a lot of tutorials and some questions here in Stackoverflow ) but I keep getting the ECONNREFUSED error. This is my Dockerfile from MySql:

```
FROM mysql:latest

EXPOSE 3307

COPY ./sql-scripts /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

and NodeJS

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /user/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

this is my docker-compose file

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    build: ./db
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: sls_db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD:
      DATABASE_HOST: db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"

  node:
    build: .
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: sls_db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD:
      DATABASE_HOST: db
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: on-failure
```

This is my db config file in NodeJS app

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const logger = require("./../config/logger");

// DB Config
const config = {
  host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
  user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
};

// MySql connection pool
const pool = mysql.createPool(config);

pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
  if (err) logger.error(err);

  if (connection) connection.release();

  return;
});

module.exports = pool;
```

Can you help me? THANKS

Comment: What does your db container log says after initialization ? I suspect it fails somehow. `MYSQL_USER: root` looks suspicious as this user is created by default by the mysql container based on official image. Also make sure that your init scripts are correctly played. Anyway, your question is missing debugging details for someone to efficiently help you.

Comment: The other thing that jumps out at me is that your code is looking for `MYSQL_HOST`, but your Compose setup configures `DATABASE_HOST`.  What's the actual complete error you get?

Comment: It looks like your application code doesn't use the 3307 port. As this isn't the default port it probably should.

Comment: @danblack 3307 is the port on the host, not the Docker network, and EXPOSE doesn't change the server port

Comment: Typo? `process.env.MYSQL_HOST` needs to be `process.env.DATABASE_HOST`

Comment: `{"message":"Server running on port 3000","level":"info"}
node_1  | {"errno":"ECONNREFUSED","code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":3306,"fatal":true,"level":"error"}`

That is the log I get